# Error while trying to convert video

Tags: ffmpeg

[image]

I'm trying to convert a MKV file to MP4.

`ffmpeg` always worked great but now, when I try to do the same thing, the process looks different and it just goes on without end. So, in the end, I don't get my video converted.

Can someone help? I tried with this command on the picture and also with `ffmpeg -i example.mkv -c copy example.mp4`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It looks like you have a file named `ffmpeg.bat` (or `ffmpeg.cmd`) in the folder. Try executing the command from a different folder. There may also be `ffmpeg.bat` (or `ffmpeg.cmd`) file in Windows search path (if this is the case, search for it and delete it).

Comment: Lol i named that file ffmpeg so i can know what it is, now i just changed its name and it works tnx Rotem